# C++ function putting garbage into array

Tags: c++

Having trouble with this function, all works fine until the add, it inserts memory address into the array instead of the new ints:

```
bool reserveSeat(string name[], int reservation[][2], int &noPassengers)
{
  bool reserve = false;
  string searchName;
  int row, seat, validRow, validSeat;

  cout << "Please enter reservation name: ";
  getline(cin, searchName);

  cout << "Please enter a Row #: ";
  cin >> row;

  cout << "Please enter a Seat #: ";
  cin >> seat;

  cin.ignore(80, '\n');

  validRow = validateSeat(row, '10');
  validSeat = validateSeat(seat, '3');

  for (int ctr = 0; ctr < noPassengers; ctr++) {
    if (seat == reservation[ctr][1] && row == reservation[ctr][0]) {
      break;
    } else {
      reserve = true;
      noPassengers++;
      name[noPassengers] = searchName;
      reservation[noPassengers][0] = row;
      reservation[noPassengers][1] = seat;
    }
  }
  return reserve;
}
```

The function is called from `main()` via:

```
if ( reserveSeat(name, reservation, noPassengers) )
    cout << "reservation made ";
else
    cout << "reservation not made ";
cout << endl;
```

all arrays are size of 12, there are only 4 entries
the validate seat function as requested:

```
int validateSeat(int& col, int max)
{
while(col>max || col < 0)
{
    cout << "Sorry, that is within an invalid range." << endl << "again: ";
    cin >> col;
}
 return col;
}
```

noPassengers is determined from the load found here:

```
 int loadArrays(ifstream & fin,string name[],int reservation[][2])
 {
int row=0;
for (; row < SIZE ; row++)   
    {
        getline(fin,name[row]);
            if (fin.eof())
            break;
        for (int col=0;col < 2; col++) 
            {
            fin >> reservation[row][col];
            }
        fin.ignore(80,'\n');
    }
 return row;
    }
```

Comment: *Which* array? You don't write beyond the bounds of the arrays? How do you call the function? What is the initial value of `noPassengers`?

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in your debugger?

Comment: the call is from main via

Comment: _' it inserts garbage into the array'_ Give a better definition about _garbage_ please. And debug your program before asking on SO please!!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: i did debug, the program runs fine. but it inserts an invalid chars somewhere and the 2 ints become -85243470 or whatever,   noPassengers is the number of records taken from a textfile, ex -    J. Doe    4     6

Comment: _'the program runs fine'_ obviously not by means of requirements :-/ ...

Comment: `code`int validateSeat(int& col, int max)
{
 while(col>max || col < 0)
 {
  cout << "Sorry, that is within an invalid range." << endl << "Please try again: ";
  cin >> col;
 }
return col;
}

Comment: `i did debug, the program runs fine`  Debugging doesn't mean keep running your code, and hope for an answer on SO to your problem.  Debugging means to go start your debugger, step through the program one line at a time, observe the values of each of those variables, and then make a diagnosis based on what you discovered during this run, i.e. code takes a different path than expected, variable(s) have the wrong value, etc.

Comment: Still haven't shown us how noPassengers is initialised and it's crucial to your array. If you want answers, you simply must give context. Obviously this is part of a school assignment and you're trying to not give much away because you're worried you'll get caught.

Answer (score 2):

`validateSeat(row, '10');` is a mistake. `'10'` would be a multi-byte character constant, which I'm sure is not what you want.

**Update:** This should be `validateSeat(row, 10)`, and the line after `validateSeat(seat, 3)`.

Also it's possible that `reservation[noPassengers]` or `name[noPassengers]` is beyond the bounds of the amount of memory you have allocated , we can't tell based on the code you have shown.

Please update your post to show where you allocate memory for `reservation` and `name` before calling this function. (show the code, don't describe the code).

Comment: actually just first time asking anything, and the editor is giving me hell posting code, its initialized from a function called load arrays, loops through the file inserting into the arrays.

Comment: Try again to post, it is important to show as that is a likely source of the problem you describe

Comment: the noPassengers is well below the array size, i get the issue no matter what the size is